# How to upgrade Django Celery App from Elastic Beanstalk Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2

Tags: python, django, linux, amazon-web-services, django-celery

I am trying to upgrade a Django Application running Celery from Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Linux 1 on running Python 3.6 to Amazon Linux 2 using Python 3.8.

I am having trouble with the Celery application.

In Linux 1 I the following file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get django environment variables
celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

# Create celery configuraiton script
celeryconf="[program:celeryd-worker]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A core worker -P solo --loglevel=INFO -n worker.%%h

directory=/opt/python/current/app/src
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998

environment=$celeryenv
"

# Create the celery supervisord conf script
echo "$celeryconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf

# Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  then
  echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  echo "files: celery.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
fi

# Reread the supervisord config
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

# Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

# Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-worker
```

I am not sure where programs are located in Linux 2, so I've amended the file as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get django environment variables
celeryenv=`cat /var/app/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

# Create celery configuraiton script
celeryconf="[program:celeryd-worker]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=celery -A core worker -P solo --loglevel=INFO -n worker.%%h

directory=/var/app/current/src
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998

environment=$celeryenv
"

# Create the celery supervisord conf script
echo "$celeryconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf

# Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  then
  echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  echo "files: celery.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
fi

# Reread the supervisord config
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

# Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

# Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-worker
```

I am now getting the following errors

```
2021/04/06 06:40:50.802882 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error: Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/03_celery-worker.sh failed with error exit status 127. Stderr:cat: /var/app/current/env: No such file or directory
tee: /opt/python/etc/celery.conf: No such file or directory
grep: /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf: No such file or directory
tee: /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf: No such file or directory
tee: /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf: No such file or directory
.platform/hooks/postdeploy/03_celery-worker.sh: line 48: /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl: No such file or directory
.platform/hooks/postdeploy/03_celery-worker.sh: line 51: /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl: No such file or directory
.platform/hooks/postdeploy/03_celery-worker.sh: line 54: /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl: No such file or directory
```

I've had a look around and cannot find how the file should now be structured.  Help most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The supervisor is not present in Amazon Linux2 by default.You just have to rewrite this script to run celery under the supervision of systems like this

```
`#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create the celery systemd service file
echo "[Unit]
Name=Celery
Description=Celery service for My App
After=network.target
StartLimitInterval=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/app/current
ExecStart=$PYTHONPATH/celery worker -A documerge --loglevel=INFO -n worker.%%h
EnvironmentFile=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
" | tee /etc/systemd/system/celery.service

# Start celery service
systemctl start celery.service

# Enable celery service to load on system start
systemctl enable celery.service`
```

Comment: I included this is `.platform/hooks/postdeploy`

Comment: No, ideally it should go in the Procfile file in the root of your repository. Just write celery_worker: celery worker -A my_django_app.settings.celery.app --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO -n worker.%%h. Super simple.